# Straight solution to add .d.ts files next to vue-cli umd lib built files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, build, vue-cli, .d.ts

I'm trying to create a **vue3 typescript package** with the help of **vue-cli** and the build command I'm using is: **vue-cli-service build --target lib --name [my-package-name] [my-component-path]**.

One of the goals is to make it easy to use for typescript developers too.

The question is, Is there any straight non-plugin-hell solution for adding typescript **.d.ts** files **next to the lib modules** created by vue-cli partial build?
I've read [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155100/how-to-create-typescript-definition-file-d-ts-for-umd-library) and one of them was creating one file for each .ts file and another one was a plugin that honestly I haven't tried it yet because well... a plugin?